# Where should server environment variables be stored in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where should I store keys specific to my development, test, production servers in my ruby project? For example where should store my development-specific amazon s3 secret and key? my config/development.rb file? One issue I see with that is if the file was a part of a public github project it would show for everyone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You store separate environment variables in `config/development.rb`, `config/testing.rb` and `config/production.rb` respectively.

However, if your files will be stored in a public git repo, you do not want to hardcode any sensitive information into them. The best method is to use either yaml files that are part of your `.gitignore` or to use Environment variables in your shell. I prefer the latter, like this:

```
PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS = { storage:          :s3,
                      bucket:           ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
                      s3_credentials: { access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
                                        secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'] }}
```

You then just set the environment variables on the system that is running the app.

If you use the yaml config file method, you **must add the sensitive config files to your `.gitignore` file**. Otherwise they will still be uploaded to your public repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at config directory, you will see a YAML file, containing database credential information. You could do the same for your cloud environments.

```
development:
  server: xiy-234
  username: hello
  password: 1325abc

production:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put those information inside a .yml file in the config directory.

For instance:

```
production:
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xx
  bucket: xxx

development:
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
  bucket: xxx

staging:
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
  bucket: xxx
```

Once this is done, you have to store those keys in a Hash by doing the following:

```
APIS_CONFIG = {'amazons3' => YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazons3.yml")[Rails.env]}
```

(You can put the previous line of code inside a `.rb` file situated in the `config/initializers` directory)

Note that you might find this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) interesting.